# Height of the tableview changes when scrolling the scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollview, tableview

```
 I have a UIView and a tableview in a scrollview. The height of the tableview is 30.
```

When i tap the UIView, the tableview should expand with all its data. When i scroll the scrollview, the tableview not retaining its height. Its height changed to 30. How can i retain the height of the tableview while scrolling?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using constraints?

Comment: I'm not using constraints.

Comment: go to file inspector and uncheck the autolayout,might it work.

Comment: it will be very difficult for anybody to help you without more information.  I suggest you paste in some code from your UIViewController subclass, how you are handling this change in size in the tableView etc.  also, UITableView inherits from UIScrollView... and scrollViews nested within other scrollViews are notoriously tricky...